# Issue with object spawning when touching the screen [LibGDX]

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my game there's raining meteorites of differnet sizes. I've tried to make it so that if you touch a bigger meteorite, it will be removed (from an array), and a smaller meteorite object will take it's place on the same place as the bigger was removed.

The problem I have is that if you touch a bigger meteorite, it will get removed and go through all other meteorite types until it gets to the smallest one and completely dissapears... all in the same touch. I obviously don't want that.  Not sure how to solve this problem either.

Here's the code that handles input:

```
private void handleInput() {
    Iterator<FallingItem> iter = items.meteorites.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        FallingItem item = iter.next();

        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

            gameCam.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));

            if (item.getClass() == SmallMeteorite.class && item.getBounds().contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) { 

                meteoriteDestroyed.play(0.5f); //play sound
                iter.remove(); //removes item from array when it's no longer needed
                item.dispose(); //dispose meteorite texture to clear up memory
                score += 20; //add to score

            } else if (item.getClass() == MediumMeteorite.class && item.getBounds().contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) { 

                meteoriteDestroyed.play(0.5f);
                iter.remove();
                item.dispose();
                score += 10;

                items.meteorites.add(new SmallMeteorite(item.getBounds().getX(), item.getBounds().getY()));

            } else if (item.getClass() == LargeMeteorite.class && item.getBounds().contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {

                meteoriteDestroyed.play(0.5f);
                iter.remove();
                item.dispose();
                score += 10;

                items.meteorites.add(new MediumMeteorite(item.getBounds().getX(), item.getBounds().getY()));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the items to the array so they still get iterated on. Instead, you need to mark them somehow so they can be changed after the iteration. There are a few ways to do this.

One way would be to keep a separate List. Clear it before doing this loop, and then add items that need to be replaced with smaller ones to the separate list. When the loop is done on the main list, then you can iterate the separate list to add the smaller versions to the main list.

But LibGDX has an even easier way. Instead of using a List to store your meteorites, use LibGDX's SnapshotArray class. It lets you iterate on a copy of the list, so your changes to the array don't take effect until you're done with iterating:

```
FallingItem[] array = snapshotArray.begin();
for (int i=0; i<snapshotArray.size; i++){ //important to use snapshotArray.size, not array.length
    FallingItem item = array[i];
  //...
        //if (something) {snapshotArray.removeIndex(i, true); snapshotArray.add(new Something());}
}
array.end();
```

But before you even try that, think about whether you actually need separate classes for SmallMeteorite, MediumMeteorite, etc. There is definitely such as thing as over-encapsulation. If these objects all behave the same but simply have different parameters, they should probably be a single class whose parameters are modified to represent the different sizes. Then, instead of removing and replacing them in the array, you would only need to change their parameters.

Side note: it's wasteful that you check `justTouched` and do the `unproject` inside the loop instead of outside it. A lot of redundant repetition there.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. You made some good points that I'll look into.